# Java InternetAddress not validating email properly

Tags: java

I have a method to validate emailAddress.

```
public boolean isValidEmailAddress(String email) {
        boolean result = true;
        try {
            InternetAddress emailAddr = new InternetAddress(java.net.IDN.toASCII(email));
            emailAddr.validate();
        } catch (AddressException ex) {
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I wrote a unit test, and it accepts abce@cdf, it is not looking for .com or something.

```
   Assert.assertEquals(
                new CustomRuleEmailService().isValidEmailAddress("abc@cdf"),
                false
        );
```

returns `true` instead of `false`

Comment: Why would it? Email is essentially user@server and server may be a server on a local network that is only identified by its hostname and not a full domain name.

Comment: go ahead with a simple `regex` verification . try this `public static final Pattern VALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS_REGEX = 
    Pattern.compile("^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Z]{2,6}$", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);`

Comment: `abce@cdf` is valid. There is no problem here to solve.

Comment: As @KonradBotor said already: the email address is user@server, so that user@192.168.1.1 is also valid

Comment: @PhillAlexakis: `.accountant` is a valid TLD that your regex would decline. Also, the puny-code encoded version of localized TLDs would be too long and the non-encoded ones would be forbidden by your choice of character groups. What I'm saying is that the internet evolves and regex approaches like this will always fall short in one way or another.

Answer (score 2):

When You check JavaDoc for `InternetAddress.validate()`, you can see:

> Validate that this address conforms to the syntax rules of RFC 822.

And in wiki for email address is described as:

> An email address is generally recognized as having two parts joined
>   with an at-sign (@), although technical specification detailed in RFC
>   822 and subsequent RFCs are more extensive

So everything is working as expected

Answer (score 0):

While `foo@server` is technically a legal Email address, it's quite feasible to want to restrict addresses to one under "real domains".

Now the definition of "real domain" is non-trivial and ever-changing, so I wouldn't attempt to code one myself and rely on existing code for that instead.

For example Guava provides a `InternetDomainName` class which provides the [`IsUnderRegistrySuffix` method](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/net/InternetDomainName.html#isUnderRegistrySuffix--) which would accept `foo.com`, `foo.bar.com` and `example.accountant` but decline `foo.thisIsNotaTld` or just `foo`.

The [main class comment of that class](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/net/InternetDomainName.html) also has a good explanation of the problem and likely solutions.